Why is my lockscreen display after boot so wide and moveable?
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my PC, and I got a display error after boot on the lock screen, display too wide and moveable, my VGA is Nvidia GT 710, and I used the proprietary, tested Nvidia driver. I checked in display settings, that I have 2 monitors (one is Unknown Display), but actually I just have one.


Looks like there is nothing wrong with it.

no, there is a problem, the screen is too wide to the sides and you know, the screen is not centered like a normal lock screen.
